# Problem with cases enviroment

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I am not able to pinpoint where the problem is - it seems that [] are the culprit there. Anyway only one of the following almost identical codes is rendered. (At the moment.)

```
$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\ 
[0,1]; & x\ge 0  
\end{cases}$$
```

$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\
[0,1]; & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

```
$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
(0,1)\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\
(0,1); & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$`
```

$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
(0,1)\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\
(0,1); & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

```
$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\
\left[0,1\right]; & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
```

$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\
\left[0,1\right]; & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

I've noticed this in an old post of mine. Although I cannot be absolutely sure, I believe it was rendered ok, when I posted it (quite some time ago). There is some discussion in the comments bellow my answer, which means that I've returned to that post a few times, so I would have probably noticed the problem.

A [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au0Nl.png) - just in case this is browser-dependent or this behavior will change.

Comment: It also happens on $\LaTeX$ sometimes; I run into this sort of problem all the time when I have equations involving commutators. It thinks you are giving it an optional parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that MathJax is incorrectly thinking that your `\\` is followed by an optional parameter because the next line starts with an open bracket (note that `\\[dimen]` is used to add space between lines).  Normally, optional parameters can have space before the `[`, and new-lines count as space, but for `\\[dimen]` it should not be allowed.  This is a bug that will be fixed in the next release of MathJax, but for now you can use

```
$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\ 
{[0,1]}; & x\ge 0  
\end{cases}$$
```

to obtain

$$\Gamma(x)=\begin{cases}
[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q; &x<0 \\ 
{[0,1]}; & x\ge 0  
\end{cases}$$